# Age calculation error related to dateString input

Tags: javascript, date

I'm working with this page level javascript and dates in the format YYYY-MM-DD. Based on my research this is an acceptable format for the Date command but when I perform calcAge on the field containing the dates, nothing is returned. Is YYY-MM-DD not acceptable?

```
function calcAge(dateString) {
  var birthday = +new Date(d.substr(0, 4), d.substr(5, 2)-1, d.substr(8, 2));
  return ~~((Date.now() - birthday) / (31557600000));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are using an undefined variable `d`, replace that with `dateString` and your function will work:

```
function calcAge(dateString) {
  var birthday = +new Date(dateString.substr(0, 4), dateString.substr(5, 2)-1, dateString.substr(8, 2));
  return ~~((Date.now() - birthday) / (31557600000));
}
```

Comment: Well that was easy. Thanks!

Comment: I'm still having trouble, actually. But I can at least get a 0 in the field now.